# JSON.stringify not able to compare object's function. How it work?

Tags: javascript

I search on net about how to compare the `Object` in `javascript`. All solution generally focus on `JSON.stringify`. `JSON.stringify` compare the object that has only absolute property means fixed value.

> [The JSON.stringify() method converts a JavaScript value to a JSON
>   string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

**There are (essentially) two built-in types in JS (`null` and `undefined` are special):**

**Primitive types** (boolean, number, string, null*, undefined*).

**Reference types** - except primitive all are treated as an object like `function`.

Why `JSON.stringify` is not able to compare an object that has the function?

```
var a = {a:'xyz',
        fun: function () { var a = 10;}};
var b = {a:'xyz',
            fun: function () { var a = 10;}};

a == b => false
a === b => false
a.fun == b.fun => false
a.a == b.a => true
```

---

I searched on net then I found `JSON.stringify` for object comparison.

```
JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b) => true
```

but when I try with modified `b`

```
var b = {a:'xyz',
            fun: function () { var a = 15;}}; //change a from 10 to 15.
```

Now I check

```
JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b) => true
```

How it possible and how to compare an object that has a function property?

Comment: Note that two different functions are never equal, even if they have the same content. The duplicates discuss this point further.

Comment: as `({}) != ({})` - there's no chance a more complex Object will compare

Comment: @WoozyCoder I already went through these question and found the solution like `JSON.stringify` but the main issue with this it prompt `true` when I changed the function variable value.

Comment: `two different functions are never equal` - you mean objects @JJJ

Comment: @JaromandaX Well yes, but the OP is specifically stumbling with functions so I chose to be helpful rather than pedantic.

Comment: that's not pedantry - it's fact

Comment: Yes, a useless fact in this case.

Answer (score 1):

JSON.stringify doesn't stringify function inside the object by default. Use a replacer like

```
 JSON.stringify(a, function(key, val) {
    return (typeof val === 'function') ? '' + val : val;
})
```

```js
var a = {a:'harsha',
        fun: function () { var a = 10;}};
var b = {a:'harsha',
            fun: function () { var a = 15;}};

console.log(JSON.stringify(a, function(key, val) {
    return (typeof val === 'function') ? '' + val : val;
}),JSON.stringify(b))

console.log(JSON.stringify(a, function(key, val) {
    return (typeof val === 'function') ? '' + val : val;
}) === JSON.stringify(b, function(key, val) {
    return (typeof val === 'function') ? '' + val : val;
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Becouse `JSON.stringify` doesn't stringify functions. It takes only object parameters.

```js
var a = {a:'harsha',
        fun: function () { var a = 10;}};
var b = {a:'harsha',
            fun: function () { var a = 15;}};

console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
console.log(JSON.stringify(b));
console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b)));
```